# When using the expressjs in Nodejs, the server keeps close_wait status after a few thousands of requests

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, tcp

I put the code below onto my server:

`var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createPool({host:'192.168.1.234', user:'root', password:'123456', database:'db_xuyou_test', port:3306});

app.post('/query', function (req, res){
    s = {};
    platform = Number(req.query['platform']) *  100000000;
    platform_upper = platform +                  99999999;
    appv = Number(req.query['appv']) *              10000;
    resource = Number(req.query['res']) *               1;

    id = platform + appv + resource;
    resource_upper = platform + appv + 9999;

    sql = 'select appv from (select min(id) as min_id from download where id >= ? and id <= ?) as a inner join download on a.min_id = download.id';
    db.query(sql, [platform, platform_upper], function(err, row) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        if (row.length <= 0) {
            s['code'] = 2;
            s['message'] = 'update！';
            res.send(s);
            console.log(s);
            return;
        }

        if (Number(row[0]['appv']) > appv) {
            s['code'] = 2;
            s['message'] = 'update！';
            res.send(s);
            console.log(s);
            return;
        }

        sql = 'select res as version, versionName, ip, port, filename from download where id > ? and id <= ? order by id';
        db.query(sql, [id, resource_upper], function(err2, resRow) {
            if (err2) {
                console.error(err2);
                res.end();
                return;
            }

            if (resRow.length <= 0) {
                s['code'] = 0;
                s['message'] = '';
                res.send(s);
                console.log(s);
                return;
            }

            s['code'] = 1;
            s['message'] = '';
            s['versionData'] = resRow;
            console.log(s);
            res.send(s);
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`

And I wrote a test which sends thousands of requests to the server. But very weirdly, the the server suddenly ran into close_wait status after processing a few thousands of requests.

As the code describes, it processes the request by selecting the data from the database and send the result back to the clients and the procedure will end.

Why it turns out to be close_wait?? How to solve it?

Thanks in advance.